# How to perform Mutation in sangria-graphql?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

Currently, I'm learning sangria-graphql from [here.](http://sangria-graphql.org/getting-started/#define-a-graphql-schema) However, I could not find any documentation for Mutation (Add, Update, Delete). Also, google won't help me much. So, can you guys provide me with any good resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutations in GraphQL are modeled as an object type, just like the `Query` type. GraphQL schema has 3 top-level entry points which are modeled as object types:

- `Query` type - the root for the queries
- `Mutation` type - the root for the mutations
- `Subscription` type - the root for the subscriptions

When you created the scheme, you can provide all 3 of them:

```
Schema(QueryType, Some(MutationType), Some(SubscriptionType))
```

Otherwise, mutations work very similar to queries, except that the mutation top-level fields are executed sequentially (guaranteed not to execute in parallel).

For further info and examples, I would recommend you to check [sangria-subscriptions-example](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-subscriptions-example) which demonstrates mutation and subscriptions in addition to normal queries. I would suggest you to start at schema definition:

https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-subscriptions-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/schema.scala#L87

Comment: I found the example in the following link much more useful than the one quoted in this answer: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-scala/8-mutations/